# In Rails, how do I create a migration that will add a column/foreign key to a table that is of the same type as that table?

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, foreign-keys, migration

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  How do I create a migration that will add column to a table that is of the same type as the table?  Further, how do I add a foreign key (it is fine if the column is NULL)?  I tried this

```
class AddLinkedMyObjectToMyObjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :my_objects, :linked_my_object, type: :my_object, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

but I got this error upon running the migration

```
== 20160616201701 AddLinkedMyObjectToMyObjects: migrating =============================
-- add_reference(:my_objects, :linked_my_object, {:type=>:my_object, :index=>true, :foreign_key=>true})
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "my_object" does not exist
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE "MyObjects" ADD "linked_my_object_id" my_object
                                                 ^
: ALTER TABLE "MyObjects" ADD "linked_my_object_id" my_object
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `block in execute'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:472:in `block in log'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do it "manually":

```
add_column :my_objects, :linked_my_object_id, :integer
add_index :my_objects, :linked_my_object_id
add_foreign_key :my_objects, :my_objects, column: :linked_my_object_id
```

Then in the `MyObject` class say this:

```
belongs_to :linked_my_object, class_name: MyObject
has_many :my_objects, foreign_key: :linked_my_object_id
```

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar.
I would add a reference in the articles table that references users. And what that does is creat an index called *user_id* inside the articles table.

1: The command to generate the migration would be:

```
rails generate migration add_user_id_to_articles user:references
```

2: The result migration would be:

```
class AddUserIdToArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :articles, :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

3: Run `rake db:migrate` in the terminal

4: The result of this migration in the scheme.rb file would be:
where you can see added t.integer  "user_id"

```
create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "body"
    t.integer  "visits_count"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
```

5: To do the association, I would add to article.rb model

```
belongs_to :user
```

And then, in the user.rb model

```
has_many :articles
```